# timestamp convert in snowflake to keep fraction nanosecond

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have date value coming as 2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678Z and would like to store it as >2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678 in snowflake timestamp data type column.

i am using following but it's always outputting 2022-11-18 00:00:01.012 .

`to_timestamp('2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF9')`

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Your first date value is coming to you as a string, and you are trying to cast that to a timestamp.  A timestamp in Snowflake is stored as a timestamp with no particular formatting.  How you want to display that value can be set as a parameter or formatted explicitly by casting the timestamp back to a string.

This query shows how you'd format the string to a timestamp:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678Z','YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9Z');
```

If you want to display that output specifically, then cast it back to a string:

```
SELECT to_varchar(to_timestamp('2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678Z','YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9Z'),'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9');
```

Or, you can use the `ALTER SESSION` to set these parameters:

```
TIMESTAMP_LTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9'
TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9'
TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9'
```

Once those are set, then the first query should return in the format that you are requesting.  The reason that your original attempt at displaying the timestamp came out the way it did is probably based on the account or session settings for the output format.

Answer (score 0):

Just Mike's answer with the middle example expanded out:

```
SELECT column1 as as_string
    ,to_timestamp(as_string,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9Z') as as_timestamp
    ,to_varchar(as_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF9') as as_string_again
from values 
    ('2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678Z'),
    ('2022-11-18T00:00:02.123456789Z');
```

| AS_STRING | AS_TIMESTAMP | AS_STRING_AGAIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678Z | 2022-11-18 00:00:01.012 | 2022-11-18T00:00:01.012345678 |
| 2022-11-18T00:00:02.123456789Z | 2022-11-18 00:00:02.123 | 2022-11-18T00:00:02.123456789 |

showing the difference when "what you see" the representation, and what actually is stored.